# Azure - add custom domain from webjob with queuetrigger

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-webjobs

I would like to have a webjob that is triggered by a queue. pretty simple stuff.

Then when the job triggers i want to extract the values and create a custom domain against a web app.

Whats the best way to achieve this? 
Can powershell webjobs be triggered by a queue?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you'd like to in term of "Adding a custom domain" ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this article:

[How to use Azure queue storage with the WebJobs SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to)

Also you can use Azure Function to trigger job from queue:

[Create a function triggered by Azure Queue storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function)

Azure Function support Powershell:

- Create a Function App
- Create a PowerShell Function:
  [image: Azure Function - Powershell templates]
- Now you have a PowerShell function triggered by a queue:
  [image: Azure Function - QueueTrigger PowerShell]

Answer (score 1):

I also had to manage the same scenario. I couldn't find stuff for webjobs triggered by queue written in powershell. So I made use of Azure function triggered by queue for setting a custom domain and binding an SSL provided by Azure. I could achieve this by using powershell. In my case I had to do a db update as well after processing the queue which also was achieved. Please make sure to add required modules in "requirements.psd1" file.

Following is the powershell script I used in a queue triggered azure function. Make sure you add environment variables to the function app configuration application settings as well (for e.g., WebAppName).

```
using namespace System.Net
using namespace System.Management.Automation

param([string] $QueueItem, $TriggerMetadata)
Write-Host "PowerShell queue trigger function processed work item: $QueueItem"
Write-Host "Queue item insertion time: $($TriggerMetadata.InsertionTime)"

$cusDomainQueue = $QueueItem.Split("|")
$fqdn = $cusDomainQueue[0]
$userId = $cusDomainQueue[1]

if ($fqdn) {
    $webappname = $env:WebAppName 
    $resourcegroup = $env:ResourceGroupName 
    $azureAccountName = $env:AzureAppClientId
    $azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:AzureAppClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
    $azureTenant = $env:TenantId
    try {
        $azureCredentials = New-Object PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)
        Write-Host "Initialized Credential"
        
        Disable-AzContextAutosave

        $azureProfile = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal `
            -Credential $azureCredentials `
            -Tenant $azureTenant
        Write-Host "Connected AzureAccount"

        $webApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $webappname
        $hostNames = $webApp.HostNames
        $hostNames = $hostNames + $fqdn

        $setDomainName = Set-AzWebApp -Name $webappname `
        -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup `
        -HostNames @($hostNames) `
        -DefaultProfile $azureProfile

        if ($setDomainName.EnabledHostNames -Contains $fqdn)
        {
            Write-Host "Set domain name successful"

            $setSSL = New-AzWebAppCertificate -Name $webappname `
                -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup `
                -WebAppName $webappname `
                -HostName $fqdn `
                -AddBinding -SslState 'SniEnabled' `
                -DefaultProfile $azureProfile 
            Write-Host "Set SSL successful" 
            $body = "Custom domain mapped and SSL certificate binding completed."

            Write-Host "Updating db"
            Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "<YourQuery>" -ConnectionString $env:ConnectionString
            Write-Host "Db updated"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Couldn't add domain $fqdn"
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Exception occurred while adding domain $fqdn"
    }    
}
```